# Docker PostgreSQL - Scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d doesn't run

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So, I have a docker-compose project with this structure:

```
DockerDev
- docker-compose.yaml
- d-php
  - Dockerfile
  - scripts-apache
- d-postgresql
  - Dockerfile
  - scripts
    - dev_data_setup.sql
- logs
- pgdata
- www
```

PHP, Redis, ElasticSearch is OK. But Postgresql doesn't run dev_data_setup.sql, with any diferent solutions to /dockes-entrypoint-initdb.d that I found (volume, ADD, COPY, etc). I tried to run and sh script and nothing.

Could you see this docker-compose and Dockerfile and help me? Thanks

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest
ADD ./scripts/dev_data_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build: ./d-php/
    hostname: www.domain.com
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
      - ./d-php/scripts-apache2/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
      - ./d-php/scripts-apache2/web.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/web.conf
      - ./d-php/scripts-apache2/webservice.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webservice.conf
      - ./logs:/var/log/apache2
    links:
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
  db:
    build: ./d-postgresql/
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/pgdata
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGDATA=/pgdata
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.1
```

Comment: Looks right to me. If you exec into the postgres container can you see your file in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Try: `docker-compose exec db ls -al /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Also posting the logs may help: `docker-compose logs db`

Comment: Well, TIL about `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` in the postgres container, so thanks for that! :)

Comment: The file is there. This is the log from db:

Comment: db_1             | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-11-02 17:11:33 UTC
db_1             | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db_1             | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/14EE338: wanted 24, got 0
db_1             | LOG:  redo is not required
db_1             | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1             | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1             | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

Comment: db_1             | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
db_1             | DETAIL:  Role "user" does not exist.
db_1             |  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found the problem.

- First: my sql script was trying to recreate postgres user. then, the dockedev_db exited.
- Second: I needed to remove all images related to db to docker-compose run the script again.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is caused by the way you use `ADD` in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest
ADD ./scripts/dev_data_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

This creates a file called `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` with the content of the `dev_data_setup.sql` file. What you want is to treat `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as a directory.

You should change your `ADD` command to one of the following:

```
ADD ./scripts/dev_data_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The trailing slash will treat the `dest` parameter as a directory. Or use

```
ADD ./scripts/dev_data_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dev_data_setup.sql
```

Which will specifically spell out the file name.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add

> If `<dest>` does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of `<src>` will be written at `<dest>`.

Comment: Thanks man, but I tried this too. It's not working. The script is copied, but the container doesn't run the script when starts database. How I say, I tried many times with many different configs, including like a mount volume. And nothing. For a while, I am using an Ubuntu image with postgresql instalation, and it's working.

Comment: Looks like you're running into this issue: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/193

Comment: Stupid suggestion: `chmod 755 dev_data_setup.sql` before you build. docker doesn't run things that aren't executable.